# Converting an IndexedSequence[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]] to Map[String, Map[String, Int]] in Scala

Tags: string, scala, dataframe, type-conversion

I am a beginner in Scala and i have a case where i am trying to fetch a particular column in a dataframe and pass it to another method for further processing.

In this case, i am able to get the column values as String. I can do either of the two:

1. Convert String to Map[String, Map[String, Int]]
2. Convert IndexedSequence[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]] to Map[String, Map[String, Int]]

The value in my dataframe is as follows:

```
[endGoal -> [a -> 10, b -> 10], max -> [a -> 30, b -> 30]]
```

The code snippet am trying to use to convert the string to Map[String, Map[String, Int]] is as follows:

```
val map = recordArray(33) //Got the String
//Converting it to IndexedSequence[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]
val result = for (line <- map; array = map.split(",").map(_.trim))
          yield Map(array.head -> array.tail.map(x => {val y = x.split(":"); (y(0).toString, y(1).toInt)}).toMap)
```

But the above code helps me get it converted only to IndexedSequence[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]

Am stuck in getting it converted to Map[String, Map[String, Int]]. Could you please explain me with an example on how to achieve the value in the required type?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: your data frame values are strings that you to parse by yourself? Is `[endGoal -> [a -> 10, b -> 10], max -> [a -> 30, b -> 30]]` a string?

Comment: What does `recordArray(33)` return? Is it a single `String`? If so then don't use a `for` comprehension on it. That's the source of your `IndexedSeq`. If it's more than just a `String` then why do you pull `line` from it but never use it?

Comment: @francoisr I did a foreach partition like this:
data.foreachPartition { rddpartition =>
        rddpartition.foreach { record =>
   var recordString = record.mkString(“,”)
          var recordArray = recordString.split(“,”)

and ended up getting a string which i was later struggling to convert to IndexedSequence[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]].

Comment: @jwvh 

I learnt that my approach towards the problem was wrong. I was trying to do something like this:

data.foreachPartition { rddpartition =>
        rddpartition.foreach { record =>
   var recordString = record.mkString(“,”)
          var recordArray = recordString.split(“,”)

where i was converting each record to a string which was not required.

I was able to use: 
val map = record.getAs[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]("map")

which allowed me to fetch the data as required.

Comment: You can then answer your question yourself in the form below so that others will be able to see it without digging through the comments.

Comment: Very good. If you've solved the problem then you should consider deleting the question. As it  stands it is confusing and misleading and not likely to be useful to anyone in the future.

Comment: @francoisr Sure, i just posted.

Comment: @jwvh If you still find it misleading after reading the answer, please let me know. I shall delete the post to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, i was taking a wrong approach to solve the problem.. My bad.. I was trying to do something like this:

```
data.foreachPartition { rddpartition =>
    rddpartition.foreach { record =>
        var recordString = record.mkString(“,”)
      var recordArray = recordString.split(“,”)
```

Which is where i ended up getting a string and then i was stuck trying to convert the string to Map[String, Map[String, Int]] and ended up getting IndexedSequence[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]].

Found 2 solutions:

1. From what i have tried above, adding:

   ```
   result.toList.flatten.toMap
   ```

converts the IndexedSequence[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]] to Map[String, Map[String, Int]]

2. I should directly get the Map[String, Map[String, Int]] from the dataframe by doing this:

   ```
   data.foreachPartition { rddpartition =>
   rddpartition.foreach { record =>
       val uid = record.getAs[String]("uid")
       val advertiserId = record.getAs[String]("advertiserId")
       val time = record.getAs[Long]("time")
       val map = record.getAs[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]("map")
       val crossDeviceUsers = record.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("crossDeviceUsers")
   ```